# Delete using a timedate column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to delete a record based on a column called `time` (`datetime`).  Below is my sql statement, and the table which I am working with.  SQL server says that 0 records are effected by this query, what am I doing wrong?

```
DELETE FROM msg WHERE (time = '5/26/2013 8:39:44 PM')


sender          receiver        msg                     time
============================================================================
bob         jen         this is a message   5/26/2013 8:39:44 PM
jen         mel         Message to pel          5/26/2013 8:44:29 PM
```

Comment: Appears to be working for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38185/1

Comment: Try this... `Select time from msg where sender = 'jen' and receiver='mel' and msg = 'Message to pel'`.  I am guessing the result will not be exactly = '5/26/2013 8:44:29 PM'. i.e., there will be some milleseconds in it.

Comment: @CharlesBretana I thought about that, however the value appears to be correct unless SQL server is hiding the milleseconds.

Comment: I would suggest you try `SELECT DateDiff(millisecond, [time], '2013-05-26 20:44:29') AS MillisecondDifference, * FROM msg` to see the difference, also note I'm using a universal time format, since you shouldn't assume SQL is using your local date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
DELETE FROM msg WHERE convert(datetime,time,101) = convert(datetime,'5/26/2013 8:39:44',101)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d386c/1) also.

Since you have column `time` already of type `datetime` so just convert the value to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work?

```
DELETE FROM msg WHERE time = convert(datetime, '5/26/2013 8:39:44 PM', 111)
```